# Testdisk not being installed on Cloudlinux

Tags: cloudlinux

I'm trying to install testdisk on a CloudLinux server but it's not working sounds the libraries aren't supported by Cloudlinux

```
yum install testdisk
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, rhnplugin, security, universal-hooks
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 85.13.201.2
 * cloudlinux-x86_64-server-6: cl-mirror.cloud.dk
No package testdisk available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Has anyone experienced that before and have a clue what to do?

Comment: Yeah, the package isn't in your currently subscribed repositories. Is this based on cent6?

Comment: Yes it's Centos 6.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`testdisk` is in the EPEL repository. You need to enable EPEL in order to install it.

Comment: Won't that cause issues or conflict with the server if EPEL repo is activated?

Comment: EPEL is reasonably safe. It is designed to not conflict with the base packages.

Comment: Ok thanks then I'll install it now. Thank you for the answer, I'll upvote it